# Rewriting WordPress URLs and parameters with nginx

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

Help , i need rewrite url with nginx .
I have installed plugin "Ajax Search Pro" for replace theme search , but when i search , i got error when i move to page 2,3 and go on , it show post from homepage , not from keyword search .

Example

```
https://abccom/?s=abc => Work , it show post from keyword search 
https://abccom/page/2/?s=abc => Not work , it show result page 2 post from homepage , not keywords search .
https://abccom/?s=abc&paged=2 => Work , move to page 2 search keyword work well , but this url is write manually , just only me know it , visitor don't know it .
```

So i need a code nginx can rewrite rules , url for this

```
rewrite that url 
https://abccom/page/2/?s=abc 
to 
https://abccom/?s=abc&paged=2

Parameter is Value Keyword and Number Page .
```

Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Spoofing the actual request URI that is seen by the WordPress is a bit tricky. That's because the WordPress core relies on `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variable to see the original request URI entered by user. Inside the default `fastcgi_params` file usually included to every PHP handler `location` block that variable defined the following way:

```
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
```

As described in the nginx documentation the [`$request_uri`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_uri) variable always contains full original request URI (with arguments). It does not get changed with the [`rewrite`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) directive, it is the normalized [`$uri`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_uri) one that does. That is, no matter what rewrite rules you use, doing that won't help to change the request URI seen by the WordPress. Moreover, using the most common WordPress-hosting nginx configuration like

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    ... PHP-FPM configuration here
}
```

every request containing WordPress route (but not the request for some JS/CSS/image assets) will end up at the second location with the `$uri` variable being rewritten to `/index.php` due to the last [`try_files`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) directive argument.

Being that said, the only way to made the WordPress see something else that the original request URI is to redefine the `REQUEST_URI` after it is defined in the `fastcgi_params` file. But before that we need to somehow obtain its new value for substitution. Here we go. The following fragment should be placed into your server block under the `server` context (outside of any existing location):

```
set $tweaked_uri $request_uri;
if ($arg_s) {
    rewrite ^/page/(\d+)/$ /?paged=$1;
    set $tweaked_uri $uri?$args;
}
```

What happened here?
The first line stores the `$request_uri` variable value into a new `$tweaked_uri` one. The second line checks if the `s` query argument is not empty (every query argument is available via [`$arg_<name>`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) variable). Next, if it isn't empty (i.e. the `s` query argument is present), the rewrite rule is applied to the current normalized URI (note that the normalized URI doesn't include the query string part and for the `/page/2/?s=abc` request the normalized URI will be equal to `/page/2/`). If an URI matches the given [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) [regex pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) `^/page/(\d+)/$` (which will match any `/page/<number>/` string), an URI gets rewritten to `/` and the query string (available via [`$args`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_args) or [`$query_string`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_query_string) variables, consider these as synonyms) gets prepended with the `paged=$1&` where `$1` is a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the `(\d+)` regex [capture group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). For the given `/page/2/` URI that `$1` variable value will be equal to `2`.

Note that using the given rewrite rule new query argument is being prepended to the existing query string (resulting in `$paged=2&s=abc`) rather than being appended to it. This is slightly differs from your example. Usually it should not matter for the WordPress core, but if for some strange reason it is, the following rewrite rule can be used instead:

```
rewrite ^/page/(\d+)/$ /?$args&paged=$1?;
```

You can check the `rewrite` directive documentation to find out what happens in each case (I provided the link earlier as well as links to documentation for every other nginx directive or built-in variable I'm gonna use here).

Ok, lets continue. What happens if the normalized request URI does not match our regex pattern? Nothing. The rewrite rule isn't applied, neither `$uri` nor `$args` variables gets changed. On the next line `$tweaked_uri` variable is recomposed using the `$uri` and `$args` variables, either changed or not. All this happens only if the `s` query argument is present in the request, otherwise `$tweaked_uri` variable remains equal to the `$request_uri` one. In every possible case `$tweaked_uri` now contains the value we need for the `REQUEST_URI` FastCGI variable.

The last part is the PHP-FPM handler location (usually something like `location ~ \.php$ { ... }`). Put the

```
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI  $tweaked_uri;
```

line somewhere **below** the `include fastcgi_params;` (or `include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` in case your handler uses that file instead - the `include fastcgi_params;` line is there). This should do the trick you are asking for.